# What is the purpose of having this face in the subtitles/lyrics?

Tags: theme-song, hayate-no-gotoku

During the first verse in the second opening to *Hayate no Gotoku* (*Shichitenhakki Shijou Shugi!* by *KOTOKO*), this face (O_O;) appears in each version of the subtitles;  the translated, romanised and original Japanese versions.

Additionally, the face is also included on various lyrics sites such as [here](http://www.animelyrics.com/anime/hayate/shichitenhakki.htm) and [here.](https://atashi.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/hayate-the-combat-butler-2nd-opening-theme-shichiten-hakki%E2%98%86shijou-shugi/)

Why is this? I've never seen emoticons or unicode faces in any other subtitles, and I don't see how it adds to the song at all. I know this is a series that doesn't take itself too seriously, but is there any explanation as to why this is here?

[image: screenshot of (O_O;)]

Comment: Even if it's not for the question, the song is worth a listen, it's a pretty good OP

Comment: It's in the source lyrics, if you take a look at the blue text behind goddess

Comment: @nhahtdh Yeah, that's why I mentioned both the translated and Japanese subtitles in the question. It's the same on the YouTube link as well. I'll edit the question for a bit more clarity.

Comment: To be clear, the emoticon is in the printed lyrics as well. Heck if I know why KOTOKO wrote emoticons into the lyrics, though.

Comment: @senshin Maybe they thought it would look KOTO-*KOOL*

Answer (score 2):

Possibly to show the reaction of the actor in the song, which seem to be surprised/heavily pressured by fact of "the demon who wears goddess mask"... *maybe*... or probably there's *no* purpose of the *kaomoji*!.. or it can be *anything*...

Considering that KOTOKO is a famous [denpa song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denpa_song) artist (read also [What is the actual meaning of "denpa"?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/27837/what-is-the-actual-meaning-of-denpa)), *anything goes*. (Note: the Japanese title even has a star in it: **七転八起☆至上主義!**)

**So, what is a denpa song?**

> Denpa song (電波ソング) is a type of Japanese music that is intentionally strange and catchy. Common features of denpa songs include intentionally off-key vocals, nonsensical lyrics and an over-the-top tune.

**Back to *kaomoji***...

*Kaomoji* is certainly rare in song lyrics, but there are some more (not necessarily denpa song). From [Yahoo! Chiebukuro](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1341628838):

> - [Koi no Tsubomi](http://www.animelyrics.com/jpop/kodakumi/koinotsubomi.htm): (T_T), (>_<), (*_*), (;_;), (T^T), (T0T)/, (*_*)
> - [Love Love Chu Chu!](http://www.kasi-time.com/item-36223.html): (><), (T_T), (#^_^#), (@_@)
> - [Happy Succession](http://utaten.com/lyric/%E5%AE%AE%E5%B4%8E%E7%BE%BD%E8%A1%A3/Happy+Succession/#sort=popular_sort_asc): (^^;), (T_T)
> - [girls](http://j-lyric.net/artist/a0006b2/l00ab4f.html): (>_<;), (≧O≦)
> - [message](http://www.kiwi-musume.com/lyrics/ikimonogakari/mysongyoursong/message.html): (-.-;)', !(><)!'
>
> <sup>(All links are link to song lyric)</sup>

Last but not least, Ryuichi Kawamura has a song titled [〔>_<〕](http://petitlyrics.com/lyrics/72858).

---

<sup>Personally, I don't consider *Shichitenhakki Shijou Shugi!* as denpa song, but perhaps it's because I'm already used to IOSYS.</sup>